# No reputation for questions/answers in site meta

Tags: discussion, up-votes, per-site-meta

I asked a question in the specific site meta and my answer was upvoted. However there was no reputation change for that site. Is that just the way it works or is that a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not earn (or lose) rep for participation on meta sites (except Meta Stack Overflow).

From the Per-Site-Meta FAQ:

> Reputation here is entirely derived from the main website; your reputation is the same here as it is there, synchronized hourly. Votes here do not affect your reputation in any way. However, you can earn unique badges here on the meta site.

Comment: Huh. Is there any reason why I have 101 on meta and for 1.1k on the main site?

Comment: @Hans: Meta Stack Overflow serves as the "Meta Stack Exchange" currently and is not specific to SO in all cases, so the reputation here is not inherited from the parent. This is the only site that does this.

Comment: That's the "except MSO" bit. Meta Stack Overflow does have it's own Rep.

Comment: oh wow, I completely missed that part. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4):

On all per-site metas except Stack Overflow, your reputation is inherited from your parent user on the main site. Upvotes/downvotes on posts on meta have absolutely no affect on your reputation.